# Harry Potter fic where Snape thinks Harry is spoiled but finds out about his abuse, also Drarry

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape, drarry

I am looking for an old fic that I found on Fanfiction.net year ago. I have tried to find it every few years with no luck.

It is a fic where Snape thinks Harry is nothing but a spoiled brat who must have grown up rich and pampered because he was the Boy Who Lived, even if he grew up with Muggles. This is until he finds out about the Dursleys; abuse.

He then does what he can to save Harry. It is a Manipulative Dumbledore and Dumbledore bashing fic. Snape proves to the Order that Dumbledore knew about the abuse and did nothing.

I also remember that it was Drarry (Harry and Draco romantic pairing), I don't remember to what extent but I am pretty sure it was because Draco also thought that Harry was rich and spoiled and was hurt that he did not want to be Draco's friend.

Comment: Please can I remind down-voters that [Fan-Fics are fair game](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site) on this site, including [tag:story-identification] questions.

Comment: Hi Little Red 24, thanks for your question and welcome to SciFi Stack exchange. Please do take the [tour] if you haven't already, and have a look around at our other questions. It looks like you've written a good question here, please do not be put off if it acquires some downvotes. When you have enough reputation, you can access [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

*Whelp* by Jharad17 (also has a sequel)

Also:

*Harry's First Detention* by kbinnz (sequel is *Harry's New Home*)

*Not a Freak* by lastcrazyhorn

Pretty sure one of those has Drarry near the end.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how these match the description provided in the question?

Comment: And if there are multiple matches, split them into multiple answers.